# Simple algebraic extension of fields

Tags: field-theory, extension-field

Let $L/K$ be a finite extension of fields such that for every $a\in L\setminus K$, we have $[L:K]=[K(a):K]$. Can we say that $[L:K]$ is a prime number?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no: if $n>1$ is an integer, and the field $K$ is such that it admits a Galois extension with group $S_n$, then there exists a degree $n$ extension $L$ of $\mathbb{Q}$ such that there are no subextensions $K \subsetneq K' \subsetneq L$. It follows that, in that case, for any $a \in L$ with $a \notin K$ we have $K(a)=L$.

To show this, let $F/K$ be a Galois extension with group $S_n$, and let $L \subset F$ be the subfield which corresponds to the subgroup $S$ of permutations $\pi \in S_n$ which satisfy $\pi(1)=1$ (or which have any other fixed point, it doesn't matter which one). It is easy to convince yourself that there are no subgroups $S \subsetneq S' \subsetneq S_n$, hence by the main theorem of Galois theory there are no subextensions $K \subsetneq K' \subsetneq L$.

As an example, the field $\mathbb{Q}$ admits $S_n$ extensions for every $n$, and hence there are field extensions $\mathbb{Q} \subset L$ of every degree $n>1$ that have no proper subextensions.

For an explicit example: the polynomial $f = x^4+x+1$ has Galois group $S_4$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. If $F=\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\alpha_3,\alpha_4)$ is the splitting field of $f$, where the $\alpha_i$ are the zeros of $f$, then the subextension corresponding to the permutations which keep the $i$-th zero fixed is just $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha_i)$. So for any zero $\alpha$ of $x^4+x+1$, the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\alpha)/\mathbb{Q}$ is an example.

Comment: @ R.P. Thank you very much. If we suppose that the extension $L/K$ is Galois. Is the answer still negative?

Comment: In that case I think the answer is positive, because a group of non-prime order will have non-trivial subgroups (just take the subgroup generated by any element of prime order), hence by the Galois correspondence there must be non-trivial subextensions. Of course, the field extensions constructed by the method described in my answer will not be Galois (unless $n=2$).

Comment: The field extensions confronting me are Galois. According to your answer, I conclude the answer is yes in the Galois extensions! Thank you so much.  You helped me a lot.

Comment: To try to convince myself that there is no subgroup $S \subsetneq S' \subsetneq S_n$: I see $S$ has index $n$ in $S_n$ (as it's essentially $S_{n-1}$). Adding in at least one more element means $S'$ will have index less than $n$. But there is a nontrivial fact that there is no subgroup of $S_n$ with index strictly between $2$ and $n$ for $n \neq 4$ (and one can treat $4$ separately). Alternately, this claim is equivalent to the fact that $S_{n-1}$ is a maximal subgroup of $S_n$, which I also think of as lightly nontrivial. Do you have an easier verification in mind?

Comment: @davidlowryduda What I had in mind was this: suppose $S'$ is a subgroup which strictly contains $S_{n-1}$ (which here means the subgroup of permutations keeping $1$ fixed). Let $s\in S'$ be an element outside $S_{n-1}$, say $s(1)=i \neq 1$. Then $sS_{n-1}$ consists exactly of all the permutations which send $1$ to $i$. But by post-composing $s$ by elements of $S_n$ I can get permutations sending $1$ to any $j$ that I want. This would seem to show that $S_{n-1}sS_{n-1}$ equals the whole $S_n$.

Comment: Correction: not the whole $S_n$, but the whole complement of $S_{n-1}$ in $S_n$, which is what needed to be shown.